# What's wrong with the OData types in an Azure REST API Insert operation?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, azure-table-storage, azure-rest-api

Consider the following code. It is using the exact JSON string as the [example from MSLearn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) with the exception of getting a numeric Partition Key and Row Key.

```
sTableName = "timstesttable"
tableSASToken = "sv=2021-10-04&ss=btqf&srt=sco&se=2123-02-16T22%3A02%3A00Z&sp=rwdxftlacup&sig={sig}"

sJSON = "{""TableName"":""" & sTableName & """}"
sURL = "https://mystorage.table.core.windows.net/Tables?" & tableSASToken
Set oRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
oRequest.Open "POST", sURL
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Date", getUTC
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Prefer", "return-content"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sJSON)
oRequest.Send sJSON
WScript.Echo oRequest.Status & ": " & oRequest.statusText
WScript.Echo oRequest.responseText
Set oRequest = Nothing

sURL = "https://mystorage.table.core.windows.net/Tables('" & sTableName & "')?" & tableSASToken
Set oRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
oRequest.Open "GET", sURL
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Date", getUTC
oRequest.setRequestHeader "x-ms-version", "2021-10-04"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
oRequest.Send
WScript.Echo oRequest.Status & ": " & oRequest.statusText
WScript.Echo oRequest.responseText
Set oRequest = Nothing

sJSON = "{""Address"":""MountainView"",""Age"":23,""AmountDue"":200.23,""CustomerCode@odata.type"":""Edm.Guid"",""CustomerCode"":""c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833"",""CustomerSince@odata.type"":""Edm.DateTime"",""CustomerSince"":""2008-0710T00:00:00"",""IsActive"":true,""NumberOfOrders@odata.type"":""Edm.Int64"",""NumberOfOrders"":""255"",""PartitionKey"":""12345"",""RowKey"":""6789""}"

sURL = "https://mystorage.table.core.windows.net/" & sTableName & "?" & tableSASToken
Set oRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
oRequest.Open "POST", sURL
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Date", getUTC
oRequest.setRequestHeader "x-ms-version", "2021-10-04"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sJSON)
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Prefer", "return-content"
oRequest.Send sJSON
WScript.Echo oRequest.Status & ": " & oRequest.statusText
WScript.Echo oRequest.responseText

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:

201: Created
{"TableName":"timstesttable"}

200: OK
{"TableName":"timstesttable"}

400: Bad Request
{"odata.error":{"code":"InvalidInput","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"An error occurred while processing this request.\nRequestId:74bcc6ea-b002-000d-5521-43570a000000\nTime:2023-02-17T22:44:18.4850227Z"}}}
```

However, if I remove the OData data types from the JSON string, it works.

```
sTableName = "timstesttable"
tableSASToken = "sv=2021-10-04&ss=btqf&srt=sco&se=2123-02-16T22%3A02%3A00Z&sp=rwdxftlacup&sig={sig}"

sJSON = "{""TableName"":""" & sTableName & """}"
sURL = "https://mystorage.table.core.windows.net/Tables?" & tableSASToken
Set oRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
oRequest.Open "POST", sURL
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Date", getUTC
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Prefer", "return-content"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sJSON)
oRequest.Send sJSON
WScript.Echo oRequest.Status & ": " & oRequest.statusText
WScript.Echo oRequest.responseText
Set oRequest = Nothing

sURL = "https://mystorage.table.core.windows.net/Tables('" & sTableName & "')?" & tableSASToken
Set oRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
oRequest.Open "GET", sURL
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Date", getUTC
oRequest.setRequestHeader "x-ms-version", "2021-10-04"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
oRequest.Send
WScript.Echo oRequest.Status & ": " & oRequest.statusText
WScript.Echo oRequest.responseText
Set oRequest = Nothing

sJSON = "{""Address"":""MountainView"",""Age"":23,""AmountDue"":200.23,""CustomerCode"":""c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833"",""CustomerSince"":""2008-0710T00:00:00"",""IsActive"":true,""NumberOfOrders"":""255"",""PartitionKey"":""12345"",""RowKey"":""6789""}"
sURL = "https://mystorage.table.core.windows.net/" & sTableName & "?" & tableSASToken
Set oRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
oRequest.Open "POST", sURL
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Date", getUTC
oRequest.setRequestHeader "x-ms-version", "2021-10-04"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sJSON)
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Prefer", "return-content"
oRequest.Send sJSON
WScript.Echo oRequest.Status & ": " & oRequest.statusText
WScript.Echo oRequest.responseText

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Output:

201: Created
{"TableName":"timstesttable"}

200: OK
{"TableName":"timstesttable"}

201: Created
{"PartitionKey":"12345","RowKey":"6789","Timestamp":"2023-02-17T22:39:21.1436354Z","Address":"MountainView","Age":23,"AmountDue":200.23,"CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833","CustomerSince":"2008-0710T00:00:00","IsActive":true,"NumberOfOrders":"255"}
```

This would be fine if all my numbers were numeric data types, but that won't always be the case. What is the proper way to specify the data type when inserting an entity with the Azure REST API?

---

Addendum:
It is not just the VBScript code. The same issue occurs using PowerShell. Properly specifying the odata data types causes the insert operation to fail. Omitting them works (but may result in the wrong data type being inferred).

```
$sTableName = "timstesttable"
$tableSASToken = "sv=2021-10-04&ss=btqf&srt=sco&st=2023-02-15T22%3A02%3A13Z&se=2123-02-16T22%3A02%3A00Z&sp=rwdxftlacup&sig={sig}"
$sURL = "https://mytable.table.core.windows.net/"+$sTableName+"?$tableSASToken"

$badJSON = '{"Address":"MountainView","Age":23,"AmountDue":200.23,"CustomerCode@odata.type":"Edm.Guid","CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833","CustomerSince@odata.type":"Edm.DateTime","CustomerSince":"2008-0710T00:00:00","IsActive":true,"NumberOfOrders@odata.type":"Edm.Int64","NumberOfOrders":"255","PartitionKey":"12345","RowKey":"6789"}'
$goodJSON = '{"Address":"MountainView","Age":23,"AmountDue":200.23,"CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833","CustomerSince":"2008-0710T00:00:00","IsActive":true,"NumberOfOrders":"255","PartitionKey":"12345","RowKey":"6789"}'
$headers = @{
    "Date" = $(Get-Date)
    "Accept" = "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    "x-ms-version" = "2021-10-04"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Prefer" = "return-content"
    "Content-Length" = $badJSON.length
}
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $sURL -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $badJSON 

$headers = @{
    "Date" = $(Get-Date)
    "Accept" = "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    "x-ms-version" = "2021-10-04"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    "Prefer" = "return-content"
    "Content-Length" = $goodJSON.length
}
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $sURL -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $goodJSON


Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At line:15 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -uri $sURL -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $ba ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand


PartitionKey   : 12345
RowKey         : 6789
Timestamp      : 2023-02-20T16:45:45.3443571Z
Address        : MountainView
Age            : 23
AmountDue      : 200.23
CustomerCode   : c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833
CustomerSince  : 2008-0710T00:00:00
IsActive       : True
NumberOfOrders : 255
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the issue you are encountering is a simple Copy/Paste typo. When you specify the type, during the POST to the API it does validation against the specified type, and because there is a typo in the value, it will fail the validation, and return `400 Invalid Input`.

The typo is in the `CustomerCode` GUID, where you are missing the `-`:

```
"CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a793e9149a57833"
```

Should be:

```
"CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a79-3e9149a57833"
```

And also in the `CustomerSince` is missing a `-`:

```
"CustomerSince":"2008-0710T00:00:00"
```

Should Be:

```
"CustomerSince":"2008-07-10T00:00:00"
```

To give you:

```
$FixedJSON = '{"Address":"MountainView","Age":23,"AmountDue":200.23,"CustomerCode@odata.type":"Edm.Guid","CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a79-3e9149a57833","CustomerSince@odata.type":"Edm.DateTime","CustomerSince":"2008-07-10T00:00:00","IsActive":true,"NumberOfOrders@odata.type":"Edm.Int64","NumberOfOrders":"255","PartitionKey":"12345","RowKey":"6789"}'
```

---

It worked when removing the types because the values defaulted to Strings and therefore will work and save as observed.

The example from the [Microsoft Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) as of 2023-02-21 has the correct values, although the page has been recently updated 2023-01-31 so it could have been recently corrected.

The reason @Sridevi Postman solution worked was because they copied the JSON direct from the [Microsoft Learn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-entity) which has the correct JSON, and that works. By using the JSON provided in this question, I can replicate the `400 Invalid Input` result in Postman, and confirm it is a JSON issue.

Comment: *facepalm* I'm going to claim that the page was wrong prior to January 30th because there's no way I could have made a typo like that. The computer always forgets my password too. And I didn't do anything before the printer just mysteriously stopped working. (I can't award the bounty for 17 more hours, but it's yours.)

Comment: I completely agree that something was wrong earlier because I found one other reference to the same page (granted, dated a few years ago) which had both typo's in it, so the documentation at one point definitely had the wrong values. Too bad we can only speculate what happened 3 weeks ago...

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper way to specify the data type when inserting an
> entity with the Azure REST API?

While inserting an entity with Azure REST API, you need to specify data type in `@odata.type` format like this:

```json
{property_name}@odata.type: "Edm.{data_type}"
```

The **possible** values are Edm.String, Edm.Int32, Edm.Int64, Edm.Guid, Edm.Boolean etc.... where you need to include based on the type of data and **odata** value in `Accept` header.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I created one table named **`timstesttable`** in my storage account like below:

[image]

To generate **SAS token**, I selected `Table` in Allowed services like this:

[image]

I generated the **SAS token** successfully after clicking `Generate SAS and connection string` option like below:

[image]

Now I tried to **insert entity** by calling REST API via Postman with below headers:

```json
POST https://<storageaccname>.table.core.windows.net/<table name>?sv=2021-06-08&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2023-02-18T14:47:19Z&st=2023-02-18T06:47:19Z&spr=https&sig=<sig>

Date:18 February 2023
x-ms-version:2021-10-04
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata
Prefer:return-content
```

[image]

When I included same  `JSON` string in Body section along with *OData data type*, entity inserted successfully with **response** like below:

```json
POST https://<storageaccname>.table.core.windows.net/<table name>?sv=2021-06-08&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2023-02-18T14:47:19Z&st=2023-02-18T06:47:19Z&spr=https&sig=<sig>
{  
   "Address":"Mountain View",  
   "Age":23,  
   "AmountDue":200.23,  
   "CustomerCode@odata.type":"Edm.Guid",  
   "CustomerCode":"c9da6455-213d-42c9-9a79-3e9149a57833",  
   "CustomerSince@odata.type":"Edm.DateTime",  
   "CustomerSince":"2008-07-10T00:00:00",  
   "IsActive":true,  
   "NumberOfOrders@odata.type":"Edm.Int64",  
   "NumberOfOrders":"255",  
   "PartitionKey":"12345",  
   "RowKey":"6789"  
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, you can call below `GET` request that lists entities of table:

```http
GET https://<storageaccname>.table.core.windows.net/<table name>?sv=2021-06-08&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2023-02-18T14:47:19Z&st=2023-02-18T06:47:19Z&spr=https&sig=<sig>

Date:18 February 2023
x-ms-version:2021-10-04
Content-Type:application/json
Accept:application/json;odata=nometadata
Prefer:return-content
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you need to include *OData data type* explicitly **only**
> when it is **not** inferred through `OData` JSON type detection
> heuristics.

So even if you don't include  *OData data type* , insert entity works without any errors as ***OData heuristics*** detects the data type in some cases.

**References:**

[Insert and update entities (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/inserting-and-updating-entities#construct-the-json-feed)

[Payload format for Table service operations (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/payload-format-for-table-service-operations#json-format-applicationjson-versions-2013-08-15-and-later)

Comment: As demonstrated in the first example, including the odata type in the request body, exactly as it appears in the documentation, results in a Bad Request. Omitting the odata information works but may infer the wrong data type. The only difference between the working and non-working code is the JSON string. One would/could/should assume the JSON string in the documentation would work.